# What is the most challenging component of being a GIS.SE moderator?

Tags: discussion, moderation, moderators

In an effort to spur more competitors in the upcoming moderator election: What is the most challenging component of being a GIS.SE moderator?  Perhaps the huge diversity of questions, from remote sensing to database administration.  Or, perhaps there is a constant battle to keep questions on track.  Whatever the answers may be, it would be good for potential moderators to know what they are getting into.

Comment: from experience - time. You tend to answer less questions and more on moderation of community driven flags.